# Position of each element

Tags: jquery

I want to get position of each elements, but it shows me only the last of them. How to get all offsets? Here's the code:

```
$("box").each(function(){
  var offsetT = $(this).offset().top;
  $("#result").text(offsetT);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3fpykegb/

Comment: how to you want to present it?

Comment: I want to be offset number in the result2. Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/3fpykegb/2/

Comment: Check the answer below

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `.append` instead of `.text` You'll probably need to add some additional formatting to make it legible too.

```
 $("#result").append(offsetT);
```

Comment: That's interesting. Is there any way format data in jquery like that?

Comment: Sure you can do `$("result").append(offsetT + "<br>")` and get a line break or add whatever additional html in there you want.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code.

```js
$("box").hover(function() {
  var offsetL = $(this).offset().left;

  $("#result").text(offsetL);
});
```

```css
box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

#result {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<box></box>
<box></box>

<div id="result">s</div>
```

Comment: I want to get rid of the functions like hover. Later, I have to make variable with this offset. But anyway, thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Ok, there are multiple possibilities for an answer. If it helps then please accept it. :)

Answer (score -1):

Your last results replacing the previous result stored in #result div